# Python 3 pymysql insert with null datetime field

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I have a table with `name` as a `varchar(50)` and `ctime` as a `datetime`.
If I execute in MySQL `insert into atable (name, ctime) values ('aname', NULL)` it works.

In Python 3 I've tried the following approaches (all generating errors):

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='ahost', port=3306, user='auser', passwd='apasswd', db='adb')

cur = conn.cursor()
```

[Attempt 1]

```
cur.execute("insert into atable (name, ctime) values (%s, '%s'), ('aname', '')

pymysql.err.InternalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'ctime' at row 1")
```

[Attempt 2]

```
cur.execute("insert into atable (name, ctime) values (%s, %s), ('aname', '')

pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")
```

[Attempt 3]

```
cur.execute("insert into atable (name, ctime) values (%s, '%s'), ('aname', None)

pymysql.err.InternalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: 'None' for column 'ctime' at row 1")
```

[Attempt 4]

```
cur.execute("insert into atable (name, ctime) values (%s, %s), ('aname', None)

pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'None' in 'field list'")
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please fix syntax errors specifically quotes and parentheses. As is, none of these attempts should have run.

Answer (score 0):

In this case You don't need to pass `ctime`, just the values that You actually set.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `atable` (`name`) VALUES (%s)"
rows = cursor.execute(sql, ('aname2'))
print("insert:", rows)
```

I run the code and works as expected, full code:

```
import pymysql

def main():
    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(
            host='localhost', user='@@', password='##',
            db='dn_name'
        )
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "INSERT INTO `atable` (`name`) VALUES (%s)"
            rows = cursor.execute(sql, ('aname2'))
            print("insert:", rows)

    except Exception as e:
        conn.rollback()
        raise e
    else:           
        conn.commit()
    finally:
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```